# Should I use the DATE() or CONVERT(date, column) when converting datetime to date in SQL?

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I'm solving SQL problems from a book, and I had to convert a datetime column to date. My first thought was to use the DATE() function, but the solution indicated the CONVERT() function.

Is there any difference between the two functions in this use case? Which one should I use?

Comment: `CONVERT()` is not supported by most databases; and nor is `DATE()`.  It depends entirely on the database.

Comment: I.e. which dbms are you using?

Comment: The solutions are based on SQL Server 2016